# Windows 7 not recognizing SATA-connected Drives

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, hardware-failure, sata

EDIT: The drives are visible in my Windows 7 Device Manager, but not in the filesystem. It says the best drivers are installed. What's going on?

I have a desktop rig as such:

- SSD1 - Windows 7 (NTFS)
- SSD2 - Linux Mint 15 (FAT32?)
- HDD1 - Storage (FAT32)
- CD Drive

With an MSI-7641 760GM-P34 FX mainboard.

Here's the weird bit:

When using Linux Mint on SSD2, it is recognizing and allowing me to access through the filesystem SSD1 and HDD1, alongside all USB-connected devices and the CD Drive.

When using Windows 7 on SSD1, it recognizes only SSD1 and the CD drive, i.e. it does not recognize SSD2 and HDD1, despite them being SATA-connected. It also recognizes USB-connected devices and drives.

How do I get Windows 7 to recognize my drives?

EDIT: Maybe I should add - though it is obvious - that the boot menu recognizes all drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sure that SSD2 is FAT32, and that might indeed be the root of your problems. Depending on how you installed Mint, the initial filesystem on the disk may or may not have been changed to a Linux standard, like ext2/ext3/ext4. The easiest way is to issue from within Mint (given that it is the only OS with access to SSD2) the command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This should produce a table for each disk, with a column called System, identifying the file system. If this is identified as Linux, then [the Diskinternals Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/), a free program, will solve all of your problems.

Comment: Sure, I knew that - SSD2 isn't so important though; what's weird is that HDD1 is not being picked up by Windows - which should definitely be happening.

Comment: And did you check the file system on both SSD2 and HDD1?

Comment: HDD1 is definitely FAT32.

Comment: You should use the command lsusb, which can be downloaded for windows here http://download.cnet.com/lsusb/3000-2086_4-75449103.html. Thatu  should tell you whether windows sees the HDD, and how. If it does, then it becomes a problem of drivers.

Comment: So Windows sees the HDD... I suppose drivers are missing.